# Handling LookVector For Flying Camera

Tags: .net, xna, lua, vectormath

I'm trying to setup a free flying camera in XNA.  I'm using Lua connected mostly to the CLR to control the camera in this instance.

I've tried the following so far:

```
dkeys={}

LocalController.KeyDown:Add(function(s,e)
    dkeys[KeyboardKey.FromInt(e)]=true
    if e==KeyboardKey.W then
        local r,x=coroutine.resume(coroutine.create(function()
            while wait(.5) and dkeys['W'] do
                local LookVector=Vector3:Subtract(LocalCamera.Target,LocalCamera.Position)
                LookVector:Normalize()
                LookVector=Vector3:Multiply(LookVector,Vector3:Create(.1,.1,.1))
                LocalCamera.Position=Vector3:Add(LocalCamera.Position,LookVector)
                LocalCamera.Position=Vector3:Add(LocalCamera.Target,LookVector)
            end
        end))
    end
end)
```

I'm obviously not doing something right because the result turns into the camera bouncing back and forth between the positive and negative form of the same point.

Here is the code I'm using on KeyUp:

```
LocalController.KeyUp:Add(function(s,e)
    dkeys[KeyboardKey.FromInt(e)]=false
end)
```

Have I misinterpreted what a LookVector is?  `LocalCamera` is the current camera object with `Target` being the position the camera is looking at and `Position` being the point it's looking at the Target from.

Comment: You're assigning LocalCamera.Position twice. Did you mean to assign LocalCamera.Target instead?

Comment: @ananthonline : Do you mind posting that as an answer?  That actually happened to be the problem.  I hate staring at things like this for hours just to have it thrown back in my face as something a silly as that.  Thanks for the help though!  Sometimes it just takes a fresh look over.

Comment: Done. Yeah, its always the little things. Glad I was able to help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning LocalCamera.Position twice. Did you mean to assign LocalCamera.Target instead?